# Created a new Servlet in eclipse but giving errors with red crossmarks saying configure build path

Tags: eclipse

Here i created a new servlet but on first line itself which has no code shows red cross mark saying configure build path

Comment: i was unable to post the image because i need 10 reputations for that

Comment: now you got 10 reputation